# Use the first two terms of the series to approximate $S$.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So I was given the following prompt:

"When $p=1$ and $x=3.1$, the series converges to a value $S$. Use the first two terms of the series to approximate $S$. Use the alternating series error bound to show that this approximation differs from $S$ by less than $\frac{1}{300,000}$."
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-3)^n}{5^n\cdot n^p}\right)$$

I guess I'm confused about how I'd go about approximating $S$. I understand how to work out the first two terms of the series and I already have, but I'm confused about the wording of the question when it asks me to approximate $S$. I also understand how to find the error bound of a given series, but the wording is also confusing me here and some clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We compute the first two terms and use it as an estimate of $S$, we want to bound the error.

The alternating series error bound states that the bound is smaller than $|a_3|$ since our approximation is the first two terms.

$$\frac{0.1^3}{5^3 (3)}=\frac{1}{50^3\cdot 3}=\frac1{125000(3)}=\frac1{375000}< \frac{1}{300000}$$

Comment: Ok I think I'm following, so would computing the first two terms just be as simple as alternating the terms between positive and negative (basically just ignoring the $-1$ in the numerator) and plugging in $1$ and $2$ for $n$?

Comment: $a_1$ is positive, $a_2$ is negative, $a_1+a_2$ is the estimate.

Comment: Ok, so it would be as simple as just plugging in $1$ and $2$ into the equation?

Comment: yes, that is right.